# Android TextView and ProgressBar not showing in LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_color_red" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/_title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bar"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/bar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dip"
        android:background="@drawable/noselect_blue"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/direzione"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:text="@string/vehicleDirection"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/direzione_value"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/id_veicolo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:text="@string/lineID"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/id_veicolo_value"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/id_fermata"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:text="@string/stopID"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/id_fermata_value"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tempo_arrivo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:text="@string/vehicleTimeLeft"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tempo_arrivo_value"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pbus_spec_panel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dip"
        android:background="@drawable/noselect_blue"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:visibility="visible">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pbus_specs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/pbusSpecs"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:text="@string/pbusSpecs"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/inner_pbus_spec"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="6dip" 
            android:visibility="visible">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/credibility"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/pbusTrust"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/barraCredibilita"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="200dip"
                android:layout_height="15dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dip"
        android:background="@drawable/noselect_blue"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dip" 
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/visualizza_percorso"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/percorso_freccia"
                android:text="@string/vehicleActionSeePath"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/percorso_freccia"
                android:layout_width="30dip"
                android:layout_height="60dip"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/expander_ic" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/View02"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:background="@color/line" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dip"
            android:id="@+id/pbus_confirm_layout"
            android:visibility="gone" 
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/quick_confirm"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/conferma_freccia"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/confirmVehicle"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/conferma_freccia"
                android:layout_width="30dip"
                android:layout_height="60dip"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/expander_ic" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <View
            android:id="@+id/middle_line"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:background="@color/line" 
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dip" 
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/aggiungi_info"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/aggiungi_freccia"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/addVehicleInfos"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/aggiungi_freccia"
                android:layout_width="30dip"
                android:layout_height="60dip"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/expander_ic" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my activity:

```
package com.atacmobile;

import java.util.HashMap;

import com.atacmobile.Model.Costants;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MoreInfoBus extends Activity{

    private static Context context;
    boolean isPbus;
    String atacid;//id fermata
    String bus;
    String pathid;
    String lineid;
    String azione;
    String direzione;
    String tempoFermateRimanente;
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    int conferme;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
         context = getApplicationContext();
         setContentView(R.layout.moreinfobus); 
         azione=getIntent().getAction();

         if(azione.equals("infobus")){
             Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
             atacid=extras.getString(Costants.ATACID);
             bus=extras.getString(Costants.BUS);
             pathid=extras.getString(Costants.PATHID);
             lineid=extras.getString(Costants.LINEID);
             isPbus = extras.getBoolean(Costants.PBUS);
             direzione = extras.getString(Costants.DIRECTION);
             tempoFermateRimanente = extras.getString(Costants.TIMELEFT);
             if(isPbus){
                 conferme = extras.getInt(Costants.CONFIRMS);
             }

         }

         TextView titolo=(TextView)findViewById(R.id._title);
         titolo.setText("INFO. LINEA "+bus);
         TextView direction = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.direzione_value);
         TextView id_veicolo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.id_veicolo_value);
         TextView id_palina = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.id_fermata_value);
         TextView tempo_arrivo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tempo_arrivo_value);

         direction.setText(direzione);
         id_veicolo.setText(lineid);
         id_palina.setText(atacid);
         tempo_arrivo.setText(tempoFermateRimanente);

         if(isPbus){
             LinearLayout lin_lay = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.pbus_spec_panel);
             lin_lay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             RelativeLayout rel_lay = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.pbus_confirm_layout);
             rel_lay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             View line = (View)findViewById(R.id.middle_line);
             line.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             TextView infos = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pbus_specs);
             infos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             TextView desc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.desc);
             desc.setText("Questo autobus non è monitorato da ATAC ed è stato segnalato da altri utenti che utilizzano RMob! Esattamente "+conferme+" utente\\i hanno confermato quest'autobus!");
             desc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.barraCredibilita);
             pb.setMax(5);
             int d = 0;
             if(conferme == 0) d = R.drawable.redprogressbar;
             else if(conferme<=2) d = R.drawable.yellowprogressbar;
             else d = R.drawable.greenprogressbar;
             pb.setProgressDrawable(context.getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(d));
             pb.setProgress(conferme<4?conferme+1:pb.getMax());
             pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         }
    }


     @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        // Checks the orientation of the screen
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        }
        // Checks whether a hardware keyboard is available
        if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO) {
        } else if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES) {
        }
    }
}
```

The above layout shows everything except the `TextView desc`, and all the `LinearLayout` with id `inner_pbus_spec`. What am I doing wrong? I can see everything in Eclipse's visual editor!

Comment: seriously its showing everything here in my case, without any problem. may be you need to check the values you are getting thru your bundle.. I looked for the views actually you had complained for only. (I had just copied your layout and code to my dummy project )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element above desc (pbus_specs) has a height of fill_parent.  That would cause it to grow and not display some of the other elements.

Comment: I setted that to **wrap_content** and it did the trick! Thanks a lot! Shame on me!